# Json-ld defining type for node

Tags: json-ld

I have a simple json file like:

```
{
   "name": "something"
}
```

Now I Have a json-ld definition where there are objects. There is object with id #something - it exists lets say on http://example.com/test.jsonld#something.

Now I want to add context without modyfying original data so Name becomes a type and value becomes IRI to http://example.com/test.jsonld#something.

I've done something like this:

```
{
   "@context":{
      "name":"@type"
   },
   "@id":"1234",
   "name":"something"
}
```

This gives me in jsonld playground almost what I want:

```
{
   "@id": "1234",
   "@type": "http://json-ld.org/playground/something",
}
```

How do I add context so value "something is expanded to IRI http://example.com/test.jsonld#something instead of playgorund ?

Tried with "@base" but it also changes the @id to url.

Answer (score 2):

You can use terms (strings mapped to IRIs) as values of `@type`. As you alias `name` to `@type` already, all you need to do is to add the mapping from `something` to `http://example.com/test.jsonld#something`:

```
{
  "@context":{
    "name": "@type",
    "something": "http://example.com/test.jsonld#something"
  },
  "@id": "1234",
  "name": "something"
}
```

> Tried with "@base" but it also changes the @id to url.

The value of `@id` is always a IRI. It is just not expanded if you don't have a base (`"@base": null`)

Comment: Thanks Markus, that is good option.

However if I had a set of definitions. Eg. "something1", "something2" etc. They would all be defined in my "http://example.com/test.jsonld#". I'd have to define every one of them in context. Is there a way to define the "name" type to automaticly prepend it's value with some url?

Please keep in mind that the main goal is not to modify existing json data, just add json-ld context.